# React.js - conditionally use dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some code to Regex some text and wrap it in a `<span />` like so:

```
highlightQuery() {
    // will output the text response from the Model, but also highlight relevant words if they match the search query
    // that the user input
    let input = this.props.model.get('value');

    if(!this.state.hasMatch){
        return input;
    }

    let query = this.props.matched.query,
        index = this.props.model.get('searchIndexes')[this.props.matched.index];

    const replaceBetween = (str, start, end, what) => {
        return str.substring(0, start) + what + str.substring(start + end);
    };

    let ret = replaceBetween(input, index, query.length, `<span class='highlighted'>${query}</span>`);

    return ret;
},

render() {

    const classes = classNames(
        this.props.model.get('type'),
        'character'
    );

    return (
        <span key={this.props.model.cid} className={classes} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: this.highlightQuery()} }>
            {!this.state.hasMatch && this.highlightQuery()}
        </span>
    );
}
```

However, this yields: `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Can only set one of children or props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML.`

How am I best to conditionally use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define an element (and its properties) before calling the `render` function, like so:

```
var return = {};
if(myCondition) {
    return = <span key={this.props.model.cid} className={classes}>
                {!this.state.hasMatch && this.highlightQuery()}
             </span>
} else {
    return = <span key={this.props.model.cid} className={classes} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: this.highlightQuery()} }></span>
}
```

Then you can just `render` the `return` var.

Comment: you probably want a better name than 'return' for a variable.

Answer (score 14):

and make sure you do not include a space between the span tags else you would run into the following error:

> invariant.js:39 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Can only set one of
>   `children` or `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

```
return = <span key={this.props.model.cid} className={classes} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: this.highlightQuery()} }>NO SPACE OR TEXT HERE</span>
```

Comment: In my case, I had a linebreak between the opening and closing tag. It generated the following warning  `Only set one of children or props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML -  react/no-danger-with-children`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use spread syntax if you are using ES2016.

```
const options = {};
if (useHTML) {
  options.dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {__html: yourHTML};
} else {
  options.children = [<ChildNode/>];
}
return <span {...options} className="myClassName"></span>
```

Comment: In case you want to investigate/ignore the potential `eslint` complaint which might show up in regards to prop spreading, [here are the docs](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-props-no-spreading.md#disallow-jsx-props-spreading-reactjsx-props-no-spreading) for it.